# Selective Resource/Infra isolation on Azure. Possible?

Tags: azure, azure-security, azure-resource-lock

Good day, folks!
I have an Azure subscription and it has multiple resources created, like App Services, Databases, Key Vault, Storage, account, etc
I want only a few people to see the full resources, for the rest of the team, I don't want all the resources to be seen.
For example -

1. Matt sees 5 App services out of 10
2. Kevin sees 10 App services out of 10
   Is this possible to create selective isolation? If yes, then how?

I tried this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json
But, did not get it. Am I looking in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation. I had a team in Atlanta, Georgia and one team in Bangalore, India. So, Team B has to see all the resources but Team A had to see only the new or selective resources.

Now there could be multiple ways to do this, but this is what I did. You can try the same. (Make sure you're owner and has the appropriate access)

1. Go to Subscriptions -> Select your Subscription
2. Got to IAM
3. Go to Roles
4. Click on Add -> Add a Custom role
5. Give it a name and fill the Description
6. You can create a JSON or Start from Scratch
7. In the JSON file, add these properties

   properties":
   {
   "roleName": "NoAccess_SubscriptionLevel",
   "description": "",
   "assignableScopes": [
   "/subscriptions/your_subscription"
   ],
   "permissions": [
   {
   "actions": [],
   "notActions": [
   "*"
   ],
   "dataActions": [],
   "notDataActions": [
   "*"
   ]
   }
   ]
   }
8. Save it
9. Now, whenever you add a new person/teammate, at first assign them this role. No moderator, no owner, no contributor, nothing!
10. Go to resource group -> create a new RG -> IAM -> Assign the access here to the new user.
11. Now, whatever you create in this Resource Group, only that would be visible to the new user.

**Disclaimer** : This is how I controlled the access. Now, there could be multiple ways to do this but this is is what I did and will save you some time unless there is a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this. This seems to be almost exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Sure. For any service/resource, the role propagates in 1-2 minutes, be patient while testing.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for the step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Does not work for me. The custom role requires at least one Action or DataAction, and at least one assignable scope. In the above example, actions/data actions are null which is not allowed. Double Quotes aren't allowed within notActions - the error message says: "Invalid notAction is present in "notActions"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible to do so. Resource locking however is not the answer. [`Azure Role-based access control (RBAC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) is the answer.

Essentially what you would need to do is assign roles to users on specific resources. For example, let's say you want you want Kevin to manage all 10 app services then you would assign [`Website Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#website-contributor) role to Kevin on those 10 app services. Similarly you would assign the same role to Matt on the 5 app services that you want Matt to manage.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. For the starting point,  appreciate it.
However, just wanted to know if the person would even be able to see the resources.
I want to control the service's visibility. People should not even be able to see the services at all.
I hope it is achievable by RBAC.

Comment: That's exactly how it will work. If no roles are assigned to a user on a resource, they won't even see that resource. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Here's a more detailed step-by-step guide:

**Create Custom Roles:**

- Sign in to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) with your
  Azure account.

  Go to "Azure Active Directory" from the left-hand menu.

  Click on "Roles and administrators" under "Security."

  Click "+ New custom role."

  Name the role, add a description, and specify the desired permissions
  (e.g., read, write) for Matt and Kevin.

  Click "Create" to save the custom roles.

**Assign Custom Roles:**

- Navigate to the resource group containing the 10 App Services.

  Click on "Access control (IAM)" from the left-hand menu.

  Click "+ Add" to add a role assignment.

  Select the custom role for Matt from the "Role" dropdown.

  Search for and select Matt's user account or group.

  Click "Save" to assign the custom role to Matt.

  Repeat the same process for Kevin, assigning him the custom role that
  grants access to all 10 App Services.

**Verify Access:**

- Make sure Matt can only see 5 App Services, and Kevin can see all 10
  when they access the Azure portal or use Azure CLI/PowerShell.

By following these steps, you can control the visibility and access level of resources within your Azure subscription based on the needs of your team members.

Comment: Custom roles in your answer will create Azure AD roles which are very different from Azure Subscription roles. Azure AD roles apply to Azure AD only and not Azure Subscription. For Azure Subscription, you will need to use either in-built RBAC role or create a custom RBAC role.